# Lower bound for permutation generator

Tags: co.combinatorics, lower-bounds

I'm interested in a problem akin to combinatorial circuits, but in terms of complexity. Apologies for missing the correct terminology, I'll appreciate any corrections.

Given $n$ inputs numbered $1 ... n$, there are $n!$ ordered permutations. I wish to reason about the time complexity of programs which generate a single such combination.

Clearly, the simplest program will be `f(x): x`, with $O(1)$. If I write down all programs for a given problem size $n$ in the most efficient way, what will be the lower bound time complexity for the one with most operations?

A trivial solution is a `switch` statement of length $n$, with $O(n)$, but this is clearly not the most efficient way. Is there theory to answer this question?

Comment: Your switch statement actually uses n log n because the return statement from each case is a number from 1 to n, which takes log n bits to write down. And this is the best you can do in the worst case, by a counting argument. (There are n! permutations, and the most you can describe in b bits is 2^b, so you need b at least log(n!) ~ n log n.) Nice question, but doesn't really seem to be research level (which is the purpose of this site), maybe better for CS.SE.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaGrochow, and feel free to move the question to cs.se if you see fit. I don't have the rep. Regarding the counting argument, it shows that the program must have at least $n \times log(n)$ bits, but why should that relate to time complexity?

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear to me you meant time complexity. The counting argument is only for program size.

Comment: I've clarified that the question is about time complexity

Comment: Using binary search in a lookup table, you can implement any permutation by an algorithm with running time $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek, but is there a way to prove a minimum lower bound? The question isn't about a better algorithm, but about about the most efficient one.

Comment: In the standard computation model of multi-tape Turing machines, $\Omega(\log n)$ is also a lower bound, as this is the bit-length of both the input and the output. Since you claim to be able to compute the identity permutation in $O(1)$ time, you presumably use a different computation model, which you however did not specify, which makes the question unanswerable.